# Does a Pareto distribution always have variance?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution

> The expected value of a random variable following a Pareto
>   distribution is $E(X)= \begin{cases} \infty & \alpha\le 1, \\
>  \frac{\alpha x_\mathrm{m}}{\alpha-1} & \alpha>1. \end{cases}$
>
> The variance of a random variable following a Pareto distribution is
>   $\mathrm{Var}(X)= \begin{cases} \infty & \alpha\in(1,2], \\
>  \left(\frac{x_\mathrm{m}}{\alpha-1}\right)^2 \frac{\alpha}{\alpha-2} &
>  \alpha>2. \end{cases}$

Why

> If $α ≤ 1$, the variance does not exist.

Since $Var X := E(X-EX)^2$, isn't it that $EX$ being infinite implies $Var X$ existing and being infinite?

Why does the Wikipedia link say that the variance is $\infty$ when $α∈(1,2]$, and doesn't exist when $α≤1$?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this the **fourth** avatar of the same question that you are posting again and again?

Comment: Not really. Bonjour, so glad to see you again. @Did

Comment: "Not really" However, it appears so. Could you explain how the present version differs?

Comment: This is the only post in which I asked why Wikipedia says the variance is infinite for some alpha and does not exist for other alpha. I guess it uses the central moment definition of variance, by which the variance should have existed always. (In the other posts, I either did not ask about specific distribution, or asked about Glen_b's different definition of variance for the specific distribution among other distributions.) Wikipedia doesn't use the definition  that Glen_b used, and doesnt agree with the central moment definition either. That is my question here: is Wiki wrong? Or I miss sth?

Comment: This can go on forever: yes, if X is not integrable then X^2 is not integrable and yes, some lax formulations of the fact that X is not integrable when X is nonnegative are that EX is infinite. Starting from these, one can start running in circles...

Comment: I think Wikipedia is using a different definition: $Var X := EX^2 - (EX)^2$, which is why it says the variance doesn't exist when $EX$ is infinite. @Did.

Comment: Quote: "This can go on forever".

Comment: There is no such thing called "forever".

Answer (score 0):

No. If a random variable is in $L_2$, it must also be in $L_1$ (i.e., if it has a well-defined variance, then it has a well-defined expectation). And $\infty$ does not count as "well-defined".

Comment: For expectation, ∞ does count as "well-defined". If you also look at the Wikipedia link, it says the variance is infty when α∈(1,2], and doesn't exist when α≤1.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. $\infty$ is a "legit" and well-defined expectation if the function to be integrated is always non-negative (resp. non-positive). This is the case for the expectation, as $X$ takes only positive values. For the variance, if the expectation is infinite the quantity $(x-\mathbb X)^2$ itself is not defined for the integration (it is not a real value: admittedly, you can say it's $\infty$), but that's not a real number, and you cannot integrate this.

Comment: @Tim
Above is "Sorry for confusion. $\infty$ is a "legit" and well-defined expectation if the function to be integrated is always non-negative (resp. non-positive). This is the case for the expectation, as takes only positive values. For the variance, if the expectation is infinite the quantity $(x-\mathbb X)^2$ itself is not defined for the integration (it is not a real value: admittedly, you can say it's $\infty$, but that's not a real number, and you cannot integrate."

Why it wasn't edited I don't know.

Comment: I couldn't edit: my browser would not show the "Edit" button because of the overflow of the (buggy) text in math mode stream.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the variance of a random variable with density function $f$ is $\int (x-\mu)^2 f$, where $\mu$ is the expected value of $f$. So it's never defined when $\mu$ is infinite.

Comment: when μ is infinite, the integral in the definition of the variance is also infinite.

Comment: OK, yes, if you want the form $\int x^2 f-(\int xf)^2,$and you end up with something of the form $\infty-\infty$, which is undefined, since its value depends on the choice of limiting process on the limits of integration.

Comment: well, according to your post, its definition is $∫(x−μ)^2f$, not $∫x^2f−(∫xf)^2$. $ ∞−∞$ doesn't appear in the formmer.

Comment: They are equivalent.

Comment: I pointed out  that they are not, in my last comment and here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004772/for-e-x-ex2-to-exist-do-we-need-ex-to-exist-and-be-finite/1005055#1005055. I am happy if you can convince me otherwise.

Comment: The $\infty-\infty$ shows up because $(x-\infty)^2$ should be $x^2-2x\infty+\infty^2$. In other words, depending on how you take the limit to get $\mu$ versus the limit to get $\int(x-\mu)^2 f$, you get different answers.

Comment: Kevin, Thanks. I realized something, something why Wikipedia wrote about the Parento distrn that way, although I still think you claim that the two are the same is wrong.

Comment: As you mentioned in your comment to my linked reply, the Wikipedia article in question uses "the one that makes a random variable with infinite expectation have undefined variance". But I don't think it is the most standard one, and [I am not alone](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91512/how-can-a-distribution-have-infinite-mean-and-variance/91515#comment233589_91515).

Comment: OK, whatever you like!