# Can Cauchy Schwarz inequality be proven using Jensen's inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, jensen-inequality

After reading a comment on [If $\mathrm{E} |X|^2$ exists, then $\mathrm{E} X$ also exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1004544/1281),
I wonder if Cauchy Schwarz inequality can be proven using Jensen's inequality?

Answer (score 11):

Here are two such proofs.

1. One standard way of proving Hölder's inequality derives it from Young's inequality, which follows from AM/GM, which can be proven from Jensen's inequality applied to the convexity of $x\mapsto e^x$.  If you take that proof of Hölder and specialize it to the case $p=q=2$, you'll have a proof of Cauchy-Schwarz which is at root from convexity.
2. I think this one is slightly less well-known.  Consider two functions $f$ and $g$ (on $[0,1]$, say, or $\{1,\dotsc,n\}$ for the sequence case).  Define
   $$ F = \frac{f}{\|f\|+\|g\|}
   \quad\text{and}\quad
   G = \frac{g}{\|f\|+\|g\|}
   $$
   where $\|\cdot\|$ is the $L_2$ norm.  (We do not assume that it is a norm; in fact we will prove the triangle inequality.)
   Note that $\|F\|+\|G\|=1$, so we can use them as coefficients in a convex combination.  By Jensen's inequality and the convexity of $x\mapsto x^2$,
   $$ (f+g)^2 = \left(\|F\|\frac{f}{\|F\|} + \|G\|\frac{g}{\|G\|}\right)^2
   \le \|F\|\left(\frac{f}{\|F\|}\right)^2 + \|G\|\left(\frac{g}{\|G\|}\right)^2
   = \frac{f^2}{\|F\|} + \frac{g^2}{\|G\|}
   $$
   Integrating yields
   $$ \|f+g\|^2 \le \frac{\|f\|^2}{\|F\|} + \frac{\|g\|^2}{\|G\|}
   = \|f\|\big(\|f\|+\|g\|\big) + \|g\|\big(\|f\|+\|g\|\big)
   = \big(\|f\|+\|g\|\big)^2
   $$
   Expanding the leftmost and rightmost expressions, we get
   $$ \|f\|^2 + 2\langle f,g\rangle + \|g\|^2
   \le \|f\|^2 + 2\|f\|\|g\| + \|g\|^2 $$
   and simplifying yields Cauchy-Schwarz.  (This proof readily generalizes to give Minkowski's inequality without going through Hölder; I learned it from Garling's *Inequalities: A Journey into Linear Analysis* (Cambridge UP, 2007).)

Answer (score 1):

We can prove [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) for $p\in(1,\infty)$ ([Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#L2) is the case $p=2$ of Hölder) as follows.

Let $q(1-1/p)=1$ and assume that $f,g\ge0,\|g\|_q=1$. Let $E_g=\{x\in E:g(x)\gt0\}$. Note that on $E_g$, we also have $\|g\|_q=1$.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_Efg\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{E_g}fg\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1a}\\[3pt]
&=\int_{E_g}fg^{-q/p}g^q\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1b}\\
&\le\left(\int_{E_g}f^pg^{-q}g^q\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p}\tag{1c}\\
&\le\left(\int_Ef^p\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p}\tag{1d}\\[9pt]
&=\|f\|_p\|g\|_q\tag{1e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: $g=0$ on $E\setminus E_g$
$\text{(1b)}$: $q(1-1/p)=1$
$\text{(1c)}$: apply Jensen on $E_g$ with the unit measure $g^q\mathrm{d}x$
$\text{(1d)}$: $E_g\subset E$
$\text{(1e)}$: $\|g\|_q=1$

Inequality $(1)$ scales linearly in $\|g\|_q$, so we can lift the requirement that $\|g\|_q=1$.